# SSIS error "UTF8" has no equivalant in encoding "WIN1252"

Tags: sql, postgresql, utf-8, ssis

I'm using SSIS package to extract the data from a Postgres database, but I'm getting following error one of the tables.

> Character with byte sequence 0xef 0xbf 0xbd in encoding "UTF8" has no
>   equivalant in encoding "WIN1252

I have no idea how to resolve it. I made all the columns in the sql table to NVARCHAR(MAX) but still no use. Please provide the solution.

Comment: The problem is on the client side. Can you get SSIS to use a different encoding? If you cannot change that, you'll have to modify the data.

Answer (score 1):

The full Unicode character set (as encoded in UTF8) contains tens of thousands of different characters. WIN1252 contains 256. Your data contains characters that cannot be represented in WIN1252.

You either need to export to a more useful character encoding, remove the "awkward" characters from the source database or do some (lossy) translation with SSIS itself (I believe "character map translation" is what you want to search for).

I would recommended first though spending am hour or so googling around the subject of Unicode, it's utf encodings and its relationship to the ISO and WIN character sets. That way you will understand which of the above to choose.

Comment: "regexp_replace(vendor, E'[\\u200e\\u200f\\u202f]+', ' ', 'gi' ) as vendor" what does this expression do?